# Riddle -- What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I remember king Arthur well, back when I was young,
>
> when I landed on the rising sun.
>
> Back when I was flat and dull,
>
> I folded to the pressure, and grew my wings.
>
> Now I'm very skilled and artistic.
>
> 1000 is a legend, it's like a dream come true.

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you an

> Origami crane

I remember king Arthur well, back when I was young,

> not sure about this one.  I did find some reference to a Walter Crane that illustrated a version of King Arthur's tales, but that doesn't really fit the rest of my theory.

when I landed on the rising sun.

> I believe this is referring to Japan

Back when I was flat and dull,

> paper is normally flat and dull

I folded to the pressure, and grew my wings.

> but after you fold it a few times (using pressure), you can create some wings.

Now I'm very skilled and artistic.

> Origami is considered an art form

1000 is a legend, it's like a dream come true.

> There is a legend that a survivor of Hiroshima (or Nagasaki) tried to make 1000 origami cranes before she died, but passed away before she could complete them.  The goal was to fulfill a dream of world peace, because the crane is auspicious.  Fellow survivors supposedly finished the cranes after she passed and buried her with all 1,000 in order to fulfill the dream.

Comment: Well done! Apologies if the king Arthur was confusing, I was trying to indicate the time when origami began, in about the 6th century.

Answer (score 2):

Are you:

> A sword

I remember king Arthur well, back when I was young,

> Sword in the stone reference

when I landed on the rising sun.

> Possible reference to the heat of a kiln, or a reference to the origin of the metal

Back when I was flat and dull,

> Started off as a sheet of metal

I folded to the pressure, and grew my wings.

> Metal is folded to create a stronger blade.  Wings could be a reference to the hilt

Now I'm very skilled and artistic.

> Swordmaking requires skill and is commonly viewed as an art

1000 is a legend, it's like a dream come true.

> It's said that katanas are folded 1000 times.  That more likely means they have been folded about 10 times to create 1000 layers (2^10 = 1024)

Comment: Good try, but not the right answer